# Multiple icons task bar git gui

Tags: gnome-shell, gui, ubuntu-dock, taskbar

When I use Git-gui I get multiple icons in the taskbar/favorites (Ubuntu Dock), see below:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? I have only one window open.

Comment: @pomsky Maybe, but I don't find a .desktop file associated with git-gui.

Comment: How are you launching the application?

Comment: @pomsky via the terminal

Comment: In that case you need to manually create one `.desktop` launcher for the application in `~/.local/share/applications` with a valid `StartupWMClass` entry first, see this: https://askubuntu.com/q/13758/480481